# invalid string interpolation: `$$', `$'ident or `$'BlockExpr expected -> Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The error I am getting:

```
invalid string interpolation: `$$', `$'ident or `$'BlockExpr expected
```

Spark SQL:

```
    val sql =
      s"""
         |SELECT
         |     ,CAC.engine
         |     ,CAC.user_email
         |     ,CAC.submit_time
         |     ,CAC.end_time
         |     ,CAC.duration
         |     ,CAC.counter_name
         |     ,CAC.counter_value
         |     ,CAC.usage_hour
         |     ,CAC.event_date
         |FROM
         |   xyz.command AS CAC
         |   INNER JOIN
         |       (
         |           SELECT DISTINCT replace(split(get_json_object(metadata_payload, '$.configuration.name'), '_')[1], 'acc', '') AS account_id
         |           FROM xyz.metadata
         |       ) AS QCM
         |      ON QCM.account_id = CAC.account_id
         |WHERE
         |  CAC.event_date BETWEEN '2019-10-01' AND '2019-10-05'
         |""".stripMargin

val df = spark.sql(sql)
df.show(10, false)
```

Answer (score 2):

You added `s` prefix which means you want the string be [interpolated](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html). It means all tokens prefixed with `$` will be replaced with the local variable with the same name. From you code it looks like you do not use this feature, so you could just remove `s` prefix from the string:

```
val sql =
  """
     |SELECT
     |     ,CAC.engine
     |     ,CAC.user_email
     |     ,CAC.submit_time
     |     ,CAC.end_time
     |     ,CAC.duration
     |     ,CAC.counter_name
     |     ,CAC.counter_value
     |     ,CAC.usage_hour
     |     ,CAC.event_date
     |FROM
     |   xyz.command AS CAC
     |   INNER JOIN
     |       (
     |           SELECT DISTINCT replace(split(get_json_object(metadata_payload, '$.configuration.name'), '_')[1], 'acc', '') AS account_id
     |           FROM xyz.metadata
     |       ) AS QCM
     |      ON QCM.account_id = CAC.account_id
     |WHERE
     |  CAC.event_date BETWEEN '2019-10-01' AND '2019-10-05'
     |""".stripMargin
```

Otherwise if you really need the interpolation you have to quote `$` sign like this:

```
val sql =
  s"""
     |SELECT
     |     ,CAC.engine
     |     ,CAC.user_email
     |     ,CAC.submit_time
     |     ,CAC.end_time
     |     ,CAC.duration
     |     ,CAC.counter_name
     |     ,CAC.counter_value
     |     ,CAC.usage_hour
     |     ,CAC.event_date
     |FROM
     |   xyz.command AS CAC
     |   INNER JOIN
     |       (
     |           SELECT DISTINCT replace(split(get_json_object(metadata_payload, '$$.configuration.name'), '_')[1], 'acc', '') AS account_id
     |           FROM xyz.metadata
     |       ) AS QCM
     |      ON QCM.account_id = CAC.account_id
     |WHERE
     |  CAC.event_date BETWEEN '2019-10-01' AND '2019-10-05'
     |""".stripMargin
```

Comment: Good, I choose user double $, Thx!

Comment: @lasclocker what is double $ here ?

Comment: @BdEngineer   '$$.configuration.name'